# EC2 Nginx Socket Io Setup

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, socket.io, mern

Would like to ask some set up for socket io in nginx on EC2.

My tech stack is MERN Stack.

In local, backend is listening to port 5000 while socket io is the same. Then the frontend is serve on port 3000

In production, I build my frontend and point the nginx root to the /dist folder
And for backend, I use pm2 to serve the backend at http://localhost:5000

My nginx config as below

```
server {
#listen       80;
listen 80 default_server;
listen \[::\]:80 default_server;
server_name  yourdomain.com;

    access_log /home/ubuntu/server/server_logs/host.access.log main;
    
    location / {
        root   /home/ubuntu/Threads-clone/frontend/dist;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
    }
    
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    
    server_tokens off;
    
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
    
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/api/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    
        # WebSocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    
    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

Then my server side code

```
---socket.js----
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
})
export { io, server, app }

---server.js---
import { app, server } from './socket/socket.js';
server.listen(5000, () => console.log(`listening on port at http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```

My client side code

```
const socket = io('/socket.io', {
            path: '/socket.io/',
            query:{
                userId: user?._id
            }
        });
```

I have two questions where the first one is should I set up cors for socket.io at server side in this case?

The second question is, how should I set it up properly. The frontend and backend did the job normally on production. Just the web socket cannot.

If review in Network tab, the webscoket shows no error, but will keep spawning new web socket connection and in my backend, no console output for user connected to web socket also. There is no error output either.

ps: The code workings normally in local using code below for client side

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:5000', {
            query:{
                userId: user?._id
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance for the helps

Answer (score 0):

I can't unfortunately answer your first question as I'm not a developer. but for second question nginx won't be able to route the traffic to your server as proxy because you configured nginx to route traffic to `http://localhost:5000;` however you run your server on `http://localhost:3000`, after modification test your configurations using `nginx -t` then reload nginx to read the new configs `nginx -s reload` or `systemctl restart nginx`

Comment: Hi, I think the nginx configuration is ok because I am not serving frontend at http://localhost:3000. I built the frontend and point the nginx root to the /dist folder.

Then, I am serving the backend (node.js) at http://localhost:5000 and use nginx reverse proxy (/api/) point to that.

The frontend and backend connection is working properly, just the socket io issue..

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not the best one to help you with that. Wishing you the best

Comment: It's ok and much appreciate for your reply